# How to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server in a MacBook Pro 11,3?

Tags: macos, ubuntu-16.04, refind

Could anybody help to post a step by step instruction on how to install an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server image on a mid-2014 MacBookPro Retina with hardware ID 11,3 without using Parallel or VMware fusion?  I would like to know if anybody has done this already by using OSX Bootcamp feature.  Also if possible also include on how to install the image via USB and NOT on a CD/DVD-ROM.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you Google this first? Are you having a specific problem or issue, or do you just not know where to start? Have you installed Ubuntu before on any sort of system?

Comment: @music2myear Hi, yes I did a google and all it points to are Ubuntu desktop images.  I did find reFind boot manager which totally bypasses BootCamp.  My next concern is how to install reFind and the Ubuntu server iso on a thumb drive altogether...

Comment: I googled this (https://www.google.com/search?q=install+ubuntu+on+macbook+pro) and found this: https://laptop.ninja/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-macbook-pro/ Which seems to indicate there's no need for another boot manager. There's no special version of Ubuntu for desktop or laptop, just for specific architecture, and as the Macbook uses x86 architecture, you just use the "normal" Ubuntu download which happens to be labeled "desktop".

Comment: I don't see anything about reFind in the document I linked, which you appear to be using. Also, Rufus is only for if you're building the USB stick on a Windows computer. The hdutil command is for if you do not have a Windows computer and have to use a Mac to build the bootable USB. Please read the instructions carefully and completely before starting the process.

Comment: Considering the instructions in step 8 I would guess that you're just converting the .iso to .img and will put in on the thumbdrive later.

Comment: I don't know. I don't have a Mac and have never used the disk utility in MacOS.

Comment: Ok, so now I am at the server installation phase.  My next challenge is how to install the server image on the allotted partition that I have created in disk utility earlier.  The options are.. 
Guided-Use entire disk and set up LVM
Manual
When I go to Manual it is saying the partition I have created is in hf mode or can't be used. From here on I don't know what to do since If I choose entire disk, my osx will be deleted and I don't want that.

Comment: @music2myear, I tried the manual approach of creating a bootable USB drive.  I was able to install the server.  But when it's time to reboot the Mac, it went straight to Ubuntu.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick
What do you need from me in order for you to investigate the logs?

Comment: So you're trying to see how to get back to MacOS, or at least have the option of selecting which OS you wish to load at boot?

Comment: @music2myear,
Yes,I want the option to choose between MacOS and Ubuntu.  It didn't give me that choice and I need to do recovery steps for MacOS to re-install the OS.

Comment: Start at section 4, perhaps: https://www.lifewire.com/dual-boot-linux-and-mac-os-4125733

Comment: I tried reFind, and my family is confused on the small font and options.  Is there a way where If I want to boot MacOS, just don't press any key, and when I want Ubuntu, press Alt key to show the reFind boot options which I only understand?

Comment: That will be dependent on the Boot Manager you use.

Comment: You mentioned this link:
 laptop.ninja/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-macbook-pro 
and you also mentioned that another boot manager is not needed.
What do you mean by this exactly not needing a boot manager then?

Comment: I did not say another BM was not needed. I mentioned that the article notes another BM is not needed. At no point in this conversation did you note that you wanted to dual-boot MacOS. This is why it is so very important to put your ENTIRE problem out and clearly describe the desired outcome. If ReFind works, then use it. Your family will get used to it. Unless this is their laptop and not yours.

Comment: Point taken, I did mention BootCamp in my main and first message which means I did need a dual boot option.  Also, I would not be asking that much help if I only need 1 OS installation... pardon if I confused you.

Comment: Ok, so you need a Boot Manager/Boot Loader of some sort. Normally, the computer starts and the hardware hands off the startup to an Operating System. If there are two OSes you need something else for the hardware to hand-off to, and that is the boot manager, which allows the selection of one of the OSes installed. You will have to determine the BMs that meet your needs and install it according to its instructions.